# Estimating upper bound for cardinality of this set of integer pairs

Tags: approximation, integers, integer-lattices

Suppose we fix positive integers $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $C > 0$. How can we estimate the size of the set
$$\{(a,b)\mid(a,b)\in\left[0,m\right]\times\left[0,n\right]\cap\mathbb Z^2, \, \, |an-bm| < C \}$$
in terms of $m,n,C$? An effective upper estimate would also work, other than the trivial upper bound $(m+1)(n+1)$.

Comment: What are some of your ideas?  Perhaps there is something there we can work with.

Comment: Hi, my original idea was to think in 3 dimensions: let $x \in [0,m], \, y \in [0,n]$ and $-C < z < C$, then look at plane $xn - my - z = 0$ in this region. Based on the surface area of this plane, perhaps I could estimate the number of lattice points $(a,b,an-bm)$ on it? It was also suggested by another person to see if I can use Pick's theorem or Minkowski's Convex Body theorem, although I didn't find a way to use these theorems effectively. 

(ps. apologies but I am not actually Polish - the name is taken from the Marcinkiewicz Interpolation Theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r = \sqrt{m^2+n^2}$. Now, $\dfrac1r |xn-ym|$ is the distance from $(x,y)$ to the line $xn-ym=0$.

Now, we estimate by measuring the **area** of the region satisfying the inequality.

The area inside the green region enclosed by the rectangle of size $m \times n$ is, by similar triangles:

$$\displaystyle mn \left(1 - \left(1-\frac{\frac Cr}{\frac1r|(0)n-(n)m|}\right)^2\right) = mn \left(1 - \left(1-\frac{C}{mn}\right)^2\right) = 2C - \frac{C^2}{mn}$$

But then of course, if $C > mn$, then the area would be $mn$.

Since the trivial upper bound is $(m+1)(n+1)$, we can multiply the correcting factor $\dfrac{(m+1)(n+1)}{mn}$ to our two expressions instead of calculating the area of the green region enclosed by the larger rectangle.

Conclusion:

$$f(m,n,C) \approx \begin{cases}\dfrac{(m+1)(n+1)}{mn}\left(2C-\dfrac{C^2}{mn}\right) & C \le mn \\ (m+1)(n+1) & C > mn\end{cases}$$

[image]

Comment: This answer makes sense and is written in a clear manner, thank you! And for the cardinality of the set itself, can we assume that it is roughly the area you wrote down in a closed form? If the green lines & the x-y axes formed a lattice polygon we could probably estimate the number of lattice points inside that region via Pick's theorem, but it's not a lattice polygon...